# SIP users can't call each other thorugh extension number in asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk

I have two sip clients registered in sip.conf file. They can call each other from XLite client. But when I want to call them using an extension number, it shows user not found error. Following is the entry in sip.conf file:

```
[ivan]
type=friend 
username=ivan
regexten=1234
secret=pwd_ivan
host=dynamic
context=default

[test]
type=friend 
username=test
secret=pwd_test
regexten=4321
host=dynamic
context=default
```

In extensions.conf file, the dialplan is as follows:

```
[default]
exten => 1234,1,Dial(SIP/ivan)
exten => 4321,1,Dial(SIP/test)
```

Please help what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to asterisk with `$ asterisk -rvvvv` to see what happens.

Verify that your peers and channels have been loaded:

```
*CLI> sip show peers
*CLI> sip show users
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set

```
qualify=yes
```

in each peer.

To see what happens do

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 4
sip set debug peer ivan
sip set debug peer test
```

Answer (score 1):

A common problem is "iptables" firewall.  If you are running CentOS or Redhat, try

> service iptables off

... and try your call again.  If it works, then just add the appropriate rules to your IPTables config. (see http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+firewall+rules for examples)